# 802.11 BSS in same frequency

Tags: networking, wifi

I am studying about wireless networks and specifically about the IEEE 802.11. I cannot understand whether two users in the different BSSs that work at the same frequency and the same location can interfere with each other or not. I know that a BSS is formed from users that use the same frequency but i cannot figure out if a nearby BSS can use the same frequency as one of its neighbours.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sharing of the airwaves is built into the 802.11 protocols. A device must share with any other device on the same frequency, even if it is not in the same network. If you consider that interference (it will slow transfers), then it does interfere. I'm not sure I would call it interference; it is really cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

802.11 WiFi uses CSMA/CA or "Carrier-Sense Multiple Access with Collision Avoidance" to ensure all stations using the same or similar frequency can co-operate.
Before sending onto the network, a station will listen to the medium to see if something else is using it, this is called "Clear Channel Assessment (CCA)". 
If the station detects energy on the medium, it assumes it is being used and will backoff for a random (very short, in the order of microseconds) time and then try again. Eventually it should see the medium is clear and be able to proceed with its transmit.

Every unicast frame sent on a WiFi network is ACKnowledged as soon as it is received by the destination, with an ACK frame. If a station transmits and doesn't receive an ACK, it will retransmit. This avoids problems where something has decided to use the medium mid-way through a station transmitting a packet, causing corruption.

All this operates outside of the concept of a BSS, as regardless of which BSS a station is in, it still needs to play fair with all the other stations on the frequency in the same or other BSSes.

The net effect is you can have many stations in many BSSs all on the same channel happily co-habiting, the downside is performance degradation as it gets harder to get a clear channel, and the likelihood of corrupt frames and retransmits increases.